# Connection to MS Access from Oracle over a DB Link

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, dblink

I need to establish a connection between a MS Access database, which is placed on a network share on a windows box, and an Oracle database on a Unix Box. I need to query the Access tables from the Oracle database. Steps I have followed:

Created a System DSN which points to the MS Access database file (mdb) on the network share. Created an file in the /hs/admin path of the Oracle Gateways directory with the entry:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = DSN 
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = off
```

I created a listener which refers to the above DSN.

On the Unix box, created a tns entry and a public database link.

Upon querying a table over the db link, the error is:

> ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path.   >Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. {HY024,NativeErr = -1023}
>   ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from DSN

However, when I create the System DSN which points to a file on a local drive on the windows box, I am able to query tables over the db link.

Please advise on where I need to make changes.